# Mips Function Call and declarion

Tags: function, call, mips

I have the two following C++ functions:

```
void arprt(int arr[], int size, int perln){
     int i = 0;

     while (i != size){
        cout << arr[i] << ' ';
        i++;
        if (i % perln == 0)
            cout << endl;
     }
 }

int expos(int arr[], int size, int dest[]){
     int i = 0, j = 0;
     while (i != size){
          if (arr[i] > 0){
              dest[j] = arr[i];
              j++;
          }
     i++;
     }
     return j;
}
```

I want to translate them to assembly (MIPS).
How can I do that?

Also, how can I call them??

Comment: _"I want to translate them to assembly (MIPS). How can I do that?"_. First you gain an understanding of what the C functions do, then you study the "MIPS32 Architecture For Programmers" documents until you have a good understanding of MIPS assembly, and then you translate the code. Or just use a C compiler to do it.

Comment: I wrote the c++ functions. i just dont really understand the calling and arguments part of mips.